# How to increase the axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I make vertical histogram. The center of the axes is located in the left bottom corner.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/bgy39kjt/102/)

But last bar went beyond the x-axis limit (point [700, 400]). I need increase x-axis. Please help me.

My svg element:

```
const svg = d3.select('#svg');
```

My axis:

```
xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([
                        d3.min(points, d => d[0]),
                        d3.max(points, d => d[0])
                    ])
                    .range([paddings.left, width - paddings.right]);

    yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([
                        d3.min(points, d => d[1]),
                        d3.max(points, d => d[1])
                    ])
                    .range([height - paddings.bottom, 0 + paddings.top]);


    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);     


    svg.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'x-axis-group')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - paddings.bottom) + ')')
          .call(xAxis);

    svg.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'y-axis-group')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + paddings.left + ',0)')
          .call(yAxis);
```

My bars:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
        .data(points)
        .enter('')
        .append('rect')
      .attr('x', d => xScale(d[0]))
      .attr('y', d => yScale(d[1]))
      .attr('width', width / points.length)
      .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d[1]) - paddings.bottom)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bars on your chart are 100 units wide, the maximum x value should be `d3.max(points => d[0]) + 100`. If you plug that into your scale, you will find your chart now covers the correct range.

```
xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([
                    d3.min(points, d => d[0]),
                    d3.max(points, d => d[0]) + 100
                ])
                .range([paddings.left, width - paddings.right]);
```

You will now find that you have made a mistake in calculating the width of the bars:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(points)
    .enter('')
    .append('rect')
  .attr('x', d => xScale(d[0]))
  .attr('y', d => yScale(d[1]))
  .attr('width', width / points.length)
  .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d[1]) - paddings.bottom)
```

Can you work out why they are too wide?

Comment: thanks, but I do not understand what's going on with the width

Comment: The width of each bar should be x axis length / number of points.

Comment: but my code contain x axis length and number of points: .attr('width', width / points.length)

Comment: How about the padding?

Comment: what about the left padding?